marginals vs first difference of random vector
Suppose I am considering a nonnegative continuous random vector $X=(X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ having $X_0=0$, and I am considering a function $f(X)$, such as the expectation of some other function $g$ of the vector, where $g$ depends explicitly only on the forward difference of the vector's independent components, $Y_i=\Delta X_i=X_{i+1}-X_i$. Say that our problem is minimizing $f$: $\inf_X f(X)$. In studying $f(X)$, when $X$ varies among all possible random vectors, it would therefore be advantageous, computationally, to have $\inf_{Y_i}$, rather than $\inf_{X_i}$, where $1\le i\le k$. Are the two formulations equivalent?
Rephrasing the question, does prescribing all possible continuous distributions of $Y_i$ yields all possible continuous distributions of $X$, the same way that prescribing all possible continuous marginals $X_i$ does? If so, would this be true also when independence is dropped? E.g. if we assume some structure, such as $X_{i+1}\ge X_i$, can we equivalently express the problem for all $Y_i\ge 0$?
I tried to show these facts by considering that $X_j=\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}Y_i$, but then I struggle in showing that all possible continuous $Y_i$ will yield all possible $X_j$, since for example I can see how $X_j$ could be continuous while one of the $Y_i$ could be discrete, without ruining the continuity of $X_j$. Is there some loss in allowing $Y_i$ varying only among continuous distributions (I'd like to stick to continuous distributions for this problem, as considering point masses makes it difficult)?
